# I am unable to pass my button's event into my function's parameter

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a simple rock paper scissors game and so far I've written this much code but I'm not sure how to get the value of my buttons (rock, paper, scissors) to pass through my function parameters.

I have identified the values in javascript using an array but also in html using "value =" inside the button tag of the selection

```js
const scorePlayer = document.getElementsByClassName("playerScore")
const scoreComputer = document.getElementsByClassName("computerScore")
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button")
const results = document.getElementsByClassName("Results")



buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    playRound(this.value)
  })
})

let playerScore = 0
let computerScore = 0

function computerPlay() {
  const selections = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
  return selections[Math.floor(Math.random() * selections.length)];
}

function playRound(playerSelection) {

  let computerSelection = computerPlay()
  let result = ""

  if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors" || playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock" || playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper") {
    result = ("you win! " + playerSelection + " beats " + computerSelection + "!")
    playerScore += 1
  }
  if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "rock" || playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "paper" || playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
    result = ("you lose! " + computerSelection + " beats " + playerSelection + "!")
    computerScore += 1
  } else if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    result = ("its a draw");
  }
  results.innerhtml = result
  return
}

scorePlayer.innerhtml = playerScore
scoreComputer.innerhtml = computerScore
```

```html
<div class="playerScore"></div>
<div class="computerScore"></div>
<button value="rock">Rock</button>
<button value="paper">Paper</button>
<button value="scissors">Scissors</button>
```

Comment: One issue I see is that `const selections = [rock, paper, scissors]` is not passing strings, but objects. What you're looking for is `const selections = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']`

Comment: Didn't want to put this up as an answer as I've rewritten the game, but you can have a look at this version: https://jsfiddle.net/3fkpx92s/ It's more clean and hopefully also better to understand. Made comments in the code where needed.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code.  It's passing the strings 'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors' to your playRound function just as you would expect it to.  the only problem with what you posted is you didn't include the element with the result class on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typos like innerhtml instead of innerHTML

Issues like

- getElementsByClassName returns a nodelist
- missing quotes in the array
- Missing showing the score

```js
const scorePlayer = document.querySelector(".playerScore")
const scoreComputer = document.querySelector(".computerScore")
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button")
const results = document.querySelector(".results")
const selections = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

let playerScore = 0
let computerScore = 0

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    playRound(this.value)
  })
})


function computerPlay() {
  return selections[Math.floor(Math.random() * selections.length)];
}

function playRound(playerSelection) {
  let computerSelection = computerPlay()
  let result = "It's a draw"; // default
console.log(playerSelection,computerSelection)
  if (playerSelection === "rock"     && computerSelection === "scissors" || 
      playerSelection === "paper"    && computerSelection === "rock" || 
      playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper") {
    result = ("you win! " + playerSelection + " beats " + computerSelection + "!")
    playerScore += 1
  }
  if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "rock" || 
      playerSelection === "rock"     && computerSelection === "paper" || 
      playerSelection === "paper"    && computerSelection === "scissors") {
    result = ("you lose! " + computerSelection + " beats " + playerSelection + "!")
    computerScore += 1
  } 
  scorePlayer.innerHTML = playerScore
  scoreComputer.innerHTML = computerScore
  results.innerHTML = result
}

scorePlayer.innerhtml = playerScore
scoreComputer.innerhtml = computerScore
```

```html
<button value="rock">Rock</button>
<button value="paper">Paper</button>
<button value="scissors">Scissors</button>
<div class="playerScore"></div>
<div class="computerScore"></div>
<div class="results"></div>
```